# Animated and interactive object on android home screen?

Tags: android, animation, homescreen

Is there a way to add an animated and interactive object on home screen on Android? For example, an object that would move on home screen and in front of icon probably like a cat walking across the screen. is it possible??

Comment: are you mean appwidget to be animated home screen in phone or in app home activity

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Look into `TranslateAnimation`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html